# Join with or include null

Tags: mysql, database

I have a two tables

The first one is called branches

```
| branch_id | location | phone | client_id(FK) | teamleader_id(FK)|
|      1    | Guadalupe| 11111 |       1       |         1        |
```

The second one is called client

```
| client_id | clientname | priority |
|      1    |    PNB     |  High    |
```

The third one is called employee

```
| Employee_id | firstname | lastname |
|      1      |   Rinnie  | Salvacion|
```

I have tried a query and resulted like this..

```
 | branch_id | location | phone | client_id(FK) | teamleader_id(FK)| client_id | clientname | priority | Employee_id | firstname | lastname |
 |     1     | Guadalupe| 11111 |      1        |         1        |     1     |      PNB   |   High   |       1     |   Rinnie    Salvacion
```

Here's my code

```
SELECT C.*, B.*, E.* 
FROM branch AS B
LEFT JOIN CLIENT AS C ON C.client_id = B.branch_ID
JOIN employee AS E ON E.employee_id = B.teamleader_ID 

Where (B.location = 'PNB' OR C.clientname = 'PNB') OR (B.location is null OR C.clientname = 'PNB')
```

I want to show two results, one with all the info like my first query, and another one wherein all the tables are shown but only the client tables have data when you search for "PNB" and others will be null...

Please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a union query, combining both resultsets:

```
    SELECT b.branch_id, b.location, b.phone, b.teamleader_id, 
           c.client_id, c.clientname, c.priority, 
           e.Employee_id, e.firstname, e.lastname
      FROM branch as b
 LEFT JOIN client AS c ON c.client_id = b.client_id
INNER JOIN employee AS e ON e.employee_id = b.teamleader_ID
     WHERE (b.location = 'PNB' OR c.clientname = 'PNB') 
        OR (b.location is null OR c.clientname = 'PNB');

     UNION

    SELECT NULL, '', '', NULL, 
           c.client_id, c.clientname, c.priority, 
           NULL, '', ''
      FROM client AS c
     WHERE c.clientname = 'PNB';
```

Comment: OMG thank you so much , that really works... I don't know about union yet that much now I must study that part :)